# Postgres in Docker - Can't set time zone

Tags: postgresql, docker, time, raspberry-pi, zone

I thought I had changed the time zone in the past, but it doesn't seem to be working now. Logging into the Docker Container and entering the "date" command returns the correct time and date. The Docker Container is running on a RPi ([Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)).

Entering the following commands in Adminer:
SHOW TIMEZONE; Returns Etc/UTC
Enter SET TIMEZONE='Australia/Brisbane'
Returns Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.
Enter SHOW TIMEZONE; Returns Etc/UTC

I have also tried SET TIME ZONE 'Australia/Brisbane'

Answer (score 1):

you can just "SHOW timezone" to show the actual timezone and them

- SET TIME ZONE 'America/Montreal'; using continent / region.
  or
- SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
  or even

[timezone configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKtwL.png)